# Add exports to final webpack vue bundle to use it as a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have a vue component that I mount directly to the dom when the page loads.
Right now I use it as a src script tag while "exporting" the registration function as a global variable in the `window` global.

in my component:

```
window.registerComponent = (element, props)=>new Vue(...)
export default MyComponent;
```

In my html:

```
<script src="MyComponent.js"></script>
<script>
  registerComponent(element, propsFromServer)
</script>
```

I'm doing this because I need to initialize it with props from the server so I only need a single request to get the component and the data.

I'm having some problems with this model, sometimes the `registerComponent` function exists and sometimes it doesn't.

I'd like to export it from the component so I can use like

```
<script type="module">
  import {registerComponent} from "/MyComponent.js";
  registerComponent(element, propsFromServer)
</script>
```

I'd find it more reliable.

It gives me an error of name not found even with `export {registerComponent}` in my component

There's a webpack setting to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    output: {
        module: true,
        library: {
            type: 'module',
        },
    },
});
```

Did it for me